# User null input check for some time and thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, timer

```
public class green : MonoBehaviour
{
    private AudioSource source;
    public AudioClip sound;
    static int result = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine("RoutineCheckInputAfter3Minutes");
        Debug.Log("a");
    }

    IEnumerator RoutineCheckInputAfter3Minutes()
    {
        System.Random ran = new System.Random();
        int timeToWait = ran.Next(1, 50) * 1000;
        Thread.Sleep(timeToWait);

        source = this.gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        source.clip = sound;
        source.loop = true;
        source.Play();

        System.Random r = new System.Random();
        result = r.Next(1, 4);
        Debug.Log("d");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f * 60f);
        gm.life -= 1;
        Debug.Log("z");
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (result == 1 && gm.checka == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("e");
            StopCoroutine("RoutineCheckInputAfter3Minutes");
            gm.life += 1;
            source.Stop();
            gm.checka = false;
            Debug.Log("j");
        }
        if (result == 2 && gm.checkb == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("f");

            StopCoroutine("RoutineCheckInputAfter3Minutes");
            gm.life += 1;
            source.Stop();
            gm.checkb = false;
            Debug.Log("z");
        }
        else if (result == 3 && gm.checkc == true)
        {
            StopCoroutine("RoutineCheckInputAfter3Minutes");
            Debug.Log("g");
            gm.life += 1;
            source.Stop();
            gm.checkc = false;
            Debug.Log(gm.life);
        }
    }
}
```

There are two problems

1. I want to make music stop and life variable decrease -1, if the user doesn't push any buttons for 3 minutes. But if the user pushes the right button, life variable will be increased + 1.  but I don't know how to get null input from the user for 3 minutes.
2. If I use `while` for this program, this shuts down… until life is below 0, I want to repeat music which is played on irregular time.

Comment: What does `result` mean? What is `gm`? How do you decide those `checka`, `checkb` and `checkc`? You should give a clean code, and remove the unnecessary parts of it.

Comment: i thought people knew it at once;;; next time, i will give my attention;;;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: Don't use Thread in Unity**

[How Unity works](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)

[Alternative to Thread](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

[Couroutine Example 1](http://unity3dcode.com/how-to-use-coroutines-and-ienumerator-unity-tutorial/)

[Coroutine Example 2](http://blog.blacktriangles.com/coroutine-class/)

* To put it simple, `Thread.Sleep` hangs to Unity and Unity can't operate for the time, and that's why it looks like running slow.

You can use **coroutines** for this problem.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine("RoutineCheckInputAfter3Minutes");
}

IEnumerator RoutineCheckInputAfter3Minutes()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f*60f);
    gm.life -= 1;
}

void RightButtonClicked()
{
    gm.life += 1;

    StopCoroutine("RoutineCheckInputAfter3Minutes");
    StartCoroutine("RoutineCheckInputAfter3Minutes");
}
```

Or, you can just turn your `a` function into a **coroutine**, if the other code sections work.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(a());
}
public IEnumerator a()
{
    while (gm.life >= 0)
    {
        System.Random ran = new System.Random();
        int timeToWait = ran.Next(1, 50) * 1000;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToWait);

        source = this.gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        source.clip = sound;
        source.loop = true;
        source.Play();

        System.Random r = new System.Random();
        result = r.Next(1, 4);
        Debug.Log("d");
    }
}
```

> **This is an example usage of coroutine based on your code** More than this is out of scope:
>
> [A pastebin link to code](http://pastebin.com/NkwNm7QX)

Comment: routinecheckinputafter3minutes function works with rightbuttonclicked function on the same time?

Comment: No. It's just a helper function. You can call it whenever you want, such as button click.

Comment: thanks ! it works well... but it works stop at  "Thread.Sleep(timeToWait);

Comment: i am so sorry to bother you.... if you know the solution ... it works very slow... when it meets the line including thread...please let me know...

Comment: Don't use Thread. Use coroutine. Read unity docs, and look some tutorials about it. Not too hard. 2-3 hours later, I can send an example. Right now, I am not available.

Comment: sorry... ;; i need not to use thread at unity... i have to use coroutine?

Comment: and i just read for coroutine at unity docs and i read about it on blog before you told me... but can not fine the hint... or something...

Comment: You tried to use it wrong. I editted again and added an example code. Hope it helps.